# Is it possible to call a function of outer AngularJS controller on page?

Tags: angularjs

Let's say controller named cOne has a function

```
    function showAlert() {
        alert("Hello, people!");
    }
```

And I have a situation like shown below

```
<div id='parent' ng-controller='cOne'>
      <span ng-click='cOne.showAlert()'>Click For Alert</span>
    <div id='child' ng-controller='cTwo'>
        <span ng-click='$parent.cOne.showAlert()'>Click For Parent Controller Alert </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can I somehow call the function of that cOne controller from the "child" div? I tried to use $scope, $rootScope and $parent. How do I do it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to assign `showAlert` to `$scope` of `cOne` controller., and from child just call via `$parent`.

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('cOne', function($scope) {
      $scope.showAlert = function() {
        alert('cOne alert');
        };
      })
    .controller('cTwo', function($scope) {});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="cOne">
  <span ng-click='showAlert()'>Click For Alert-1</span>
  <div ng-controller="cTwo">
    <span ng-click='$parent.showAlert()'>Click For Alert-2</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should bind your function to either `scope` or controller instance. If it is bound to scope

```
$scope.showAlert = function () {
    alert("Hello, people!");
}
```

you'll be able to call it like

```
<span ng-click='$parent.showAlert()'>Click For Parent Controller Alert </span>
```

If you bind it to controller instance, you'll be able to call it in a way, you've just posted.